# Cant't find/install clinfo?

Tags: software-installation

I wanted to install clinfo by this command:

```
sudo apt-get install clinfo
```

and I get this message from the terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done clinfo is already the newest version
(2.1.16.01.12-1). The following packages were automatically installed
and are no longer required:   fairymax fonts-horai-umefont
fonts-unfonts-core gnucash-common gnucash-docs   guile-2.0 hoichess
javascript-common libaqbanking-data libaqbanking35  
libaqbanking35-plugins libaqebics0 libaqhbci22 libaqofxconnect7  
libasyncns0:i386 libclass-singleton-perl libcommon-sense-perl  
libdate-manip-perl libdatetime-locale-perl libdatetime-perl  
libdatetime-timezone-perl libdbi1 libexif12:i386 libfinance-quote-perl
libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgoffice-0.8-8  
libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgpm2:i386 libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common
libgsl2   libgwengui-gtk2-0 libgwenhywfar-data libgwenhywfar60  
libhtml-tableextract-perl libice6:i386 libieee1284-3:i386  
libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjs-jquery
libjson-c2:i386   libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl libktoblzcheck1v5
liblcms2-2:i386   libmodule-implementation-perl libmodule-runtime-perl
libofx6 libogg0:i386   libosp5 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386
libparams-classify-perl   libparams-validate-perl libpq5
libsamplerate0:i386 libsm6:i386   libtry-tiny-perl
libtypes-serialiser-perl libwebkitgtk-1.0-0   libwebkitgtk-1.0-common
libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386   libxcb1:i386
libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386   libxdmcp6:i386
libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxmlsec1  
libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386
linux-headers-4.8.0-36   linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic
linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic   linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic
python-cairo python-gobject-2 python-gtk2   snap-confine xboard Use
'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0
to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

As I understand this message clinfo is installed. However, I can't find it anywhere in my PC. It did not appear in the side bar on desktop nor I can find it by Search your Computer. 
Where is the problem? Thanks!

EDIT:
from the terminal: `dpkg -L clinfo`

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/clinfo.1.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/clinfo
/usr/share/doc/clinfo/copyright
/usr/share/doc/clinfo/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/clinfo
```

After finally finding the right folder I right clicked on clinfo and pressed "Run", but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can see which version of `clinfo` is installed with `dpkg -l clinfo`. You can see the files installed by the `clinfo` package with `dpkg -L clinfo`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried what you said and got this from the terminal:



/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/clinfo.1.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/clinfo
/usr/share/doc/clinfo/copyright
/usr/share/doc/clinfo/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/clinfo



After finally finding the right folder I right clicked on clinfo and pressed "Run", but nothing happens.

Comment: If you edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/941030/edit ) your question, and insert the text there, you could format it so that it is readable with the '{}' tool.  From what you've posted, `clinfo` doesn't come with a GUI startup file. Note: application startup files are usually called `*.desktop`. You'll have to start `clinfo` from a terminal. <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-T</kbd>

Comment: I see. What i s the command to start a program from the terminal? thanks!

Comment: `clinfo` then hit Enter.

Comment: Yes. I just realized this with other programs, but it doesn't work with clinfo. The terminal says "Number of platforms " when I enter clinfo and press enter ??

Comment: Read `man clinfo` or http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/clinfo.1.html

Comment: hmm.. I read and I do not understand this.  ??